# Java Spring Bean creation with properties file

Tags: java, spring

I have what is likely a simple question but I am new to Spring so please forgive me. Can someone please explain how I can use Class A with Spring in Class B, and how I can set Class A's fields via property file?

I have two classes:

```
public class ClassA {
   private int databaseUser;
   private int databasePassword;

   //Getters and setters for the two fields

}
```

Now the second class:

```
    //ClassB(requires Class A along with the databaseUser and databasePassword)
    public class ClassB {
       @AutoWired
       private ClassA classA

       public void setClassA(Class A classA) {
       this.classA = classA;
       }
    }
```

I then have two properties in property file located in another module /src/main/resources/app.properties, which I need to read to set the values. Properties look like this:

```
db.username=xyz
db.password=abc
```

Now my application context in the original module where class A and B reside:

```
<bean id="classA" class="com.blah.ClassA">
    <property name="databaseUser" value="${db.username}"/>
    <property name="databasePassword" value="${db.password}"/>
</bean>
```

Class Structure:

```
Module 1
-com.blah
--ClassA
--ClassB
-resources/ApplicationContext.xml

Module 2
-resources/app.properties
```

Comment: Before you try injecting A to B, can you just do a quick experiment inside your running code to make sure A has the values you need? Or this a problem where A doesn't get injected into B?

Comment: I am currently struggling with this as well. I am attempting to use @Value("${db.username}") style wiring in class A instead of xml config, though.